# How to turn off the prompts for additional participants in event registration

Tags: civievent

I have an event with a $10/head admission fee.  I have "register multiple participants" and "same email address" boxes checked in the setup.  The profile is just first name, last name and email.  The problem is that each registrant is still taken to a profile screen for each person they are registering.  So if Suzie is buying 6 tickets, she will be prompted to enter data on all six people.  They may be optional, but they are still annoying to the user.  How do you turn that off so Suzie can just say she wants 6 tickets, enter her own data, pay the fee and be done?

Answer (score 2):

Create a price set with options set at 1 Ticket $10, 2 Tickets $20, 3 Tickets $30 and so on.

Uncheck Register Multiple Participants, and use the price set you just created.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create one option field of "Input Field Type" Text/numeric quantity.  Suzie can then just enter in 6.